# how to optimize this query further more

Tags: mysql

> I tried all i could do but could not get the least execution time.

```
SELECT e.code_assigned, 
       Count(DISTINCT tcp.id) AS total_qa, 
       Count(DISTINCT tcp.encounter_uid) AS total_records,
       Sum(IF(tcp.qa_disagree = '1', tcd.weight, 0)) AS error_points,
       Sum(IF(tcp.qa_disagree = '1',1,0)) AS total_disagree,
       Sum(tcd.weight) AS total_qa_weight,
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tcp.qa_disagree = '1' THEN tcp.encounter_uid end) AS total_disagree_record

FROM tbl_encounter_detail AS e 
STRAIGHT_JOIN tbl_event_cpt_pro AS tcp ON tcp.encounter_uid = e.encounter_uid AND tcp.work_item_uid = e.work_item_uid    
JOIN tbl_encounter as ed ON tcp.encounter_uid = ed.encounter_uid
LEFT JOIN tbl_code_weight AS tcd ON tcd.code = tcp.procedure_num    

WHERE  e.qa_complete = 1 
GROUP  BY code_assigned

UNION ALL

SELECT e.code_assigned, 
       Count(DISTINCT tcf.id) AS total_qa,
       Count(DISTINCT tcf.encounter_uid) AS total_records,
       Sum(IF(tcf.qa_disagree = '1', tcd.weight, 0)) AS error_points,
       Sum(IF(tcf.qa_disagree = '1',1,0)) AS total_disagree,
       Sum(tcd.weight) AS total_qa_weight,                    
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tcf.qa_disagree = '1' THEN tcf.encounter_uid end) AS total_disagree_record

FROM tbl_encounter_detail AS e 
STRAIGHT_JOIN  tbl_event_cpt_fac AS tcf ON tcf.encounter_uid = e.encounter_uid AND tcf.work_item_uid = e.work_item_uid   
JOIN tbl_encounter as ed ON tcf.encounter_uid = ed.encounter_uid
LEFT JOIN tbl_code_weight AS tcd ON tcd.code = tcf.procedure_num

WHERE e.qa_complete = 1 
GROUP BY code_assigned
```

> This query is hampering performance (this is the least that i am able to do) I don't know why am i not able to optimize it more. what is really hampering it? Please help.

[new explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Jt9.png)

> for tbl_event_cpt_pro and tbl_event_cpt_fac

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_event_cpt_pro` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`encounter_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`procedure_num` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`procedure_qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`procedure_modifier1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`procedure_modifier2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`procedure_provider` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
`mid_provider` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
`userid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`user_time_entered` datetime NOT NULL,
`qa_disagree` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`qa_procedure_num` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_procedure_qty` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_procedure_modifier` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_procedure_provider` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_userid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_user_time_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`qa_reason` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
`work_item_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_time_entered_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`cosigning_physician` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
`procedure_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date procedure was
 performed. May not be date of service/admit date.',
`charge_code_select` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If the
procedure CPT has multiple charge codes, this indicates the one chosen    by coder',
`specialist` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Indicates   Specialist outpatient procedure - ref IU and Sturdy',
`dos` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `idx_enc_uid` (`encounter_uid`),
 KEY `procedure_provider` (`procedure_provider`),
 KEY `mid_provider` (`mid_provider`),
 KEY `qa_procedure_provider` (`qa_procedure_provider`),
 KEY `userid` (`userid`),
 KEY `qa_userid` (`qa_userid`),
 KEY `work_item_uid` (`work_item_uid`),
 KEY `work_item_uid_2` (`work_item_uid`,`encounter_uid`),
 KEY `cosigning_physician` (`cosigning_physician`),
 KEY `code_index` (`procedure_num`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`encounter_uid`)   REFERENCES `tbl_encounter` (`encounter_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`work_item_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_work_item` (`work_item_uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`work_item_uid`,  `encounter_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_encounter_detail` (`work_item_uid`, `encounter_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY (`cosigning_physician`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_lov`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`procedure_provider`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_lov`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`mid_provider`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_lov`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`qa_procedure_provider`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_lov`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`qa_userid`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`work_item_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_work_item` (`work_item_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_event_cpt_pro_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`encounter_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_encounter` (`encounter_uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

)

> for tbl_encounter_detail

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_encounter_detail` (
 `enc_detail_uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `encounter_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `work_item_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `code_assigned` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coding_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `code_complete_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `code_complete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `suspend_active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `qa_flag` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `qa_complete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `qa_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `qa_complete_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `qa_assigned` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dataentry_complete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dataentry_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `dataentry_complete_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `dataentry_assigned` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `encounter_status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `dataentry_assigned_tec` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data entry user for Technical component',
 `dataentry_complete_tec` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Data Entry complete for Technical component; used only for split data entry clients',
 `dataentry_assigned_pf` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data entry user for Profee component',
 `dataentry_complete_pf` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Data Entry complete for Profee component',
 `qa_feedback` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Set when the QA reviewer has feedback on disagreements',
 `qa_seen_by_coder_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Set when the coder acknowledges QA feedback on this encounter',
 `qa_dataentry` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Set if data entry requested QA',
 `code_complete_pf` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'When LiveCode and split data entry are active, this indicates Profee coding is done; otherwise ignored',
 `qa_requested` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Whether QA was requested by Coder or Data Entry (vs random sample)',
 PRIMARY KEY (`enc_detail_uid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uniq_wi_enc` (`work_item_uid`,`encounter_uid`),
 KEY `idx_enc_uid` (`encounter_uid`),
 KEY `idx_code_assigned` (`code_assigned`),
 KEY `encounter_status` (`encounter_status`),
 KEY `qa_assigned` (`qa_assigned`),
 KEY `dataentry_assigned` (`dataentry_assigned`),
 KEY `dataentry_assigned_tec` (`dataentry_assigned_tec`),
 KEY `dataentry_assigned_pf` (`dataentry_assigned_pf`),
 KEY `idx_qa_complete` (`qa_complete`),
 KEY `idx_composite` (`qa_complete`,`code_assigned`,`encounter_uid`,`work_item_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`encounter_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_encounter` (`encounter_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`work_item_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_work_item` (`work_item_uid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`code_assigned`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`qa_assigned`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`dataentry_assigned`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`dataentry_assigned_tec`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`dataentry_assigned_pf`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`user_email_address`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_detail_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`encounter_status`) REFERENCES `tbl_encounter_status` (`id`)
```

)

> for tbl_encounter

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_encounter` (
`encounter_uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`patient_name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`patient_sex` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`patient_dob` date NOT NULL,
`encounter_dos` date NOT NULL,
`batch_control` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_location` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`facility_id` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`patient_mrn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`patient_fin` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`encounter_lwbs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_ama` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_reason_for_visit` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_chief_complaint` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_ins_type` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_ins_1` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_ins_2` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_primary_type` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_primary_class` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_secondary_type` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_secondary_class` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_disch_diagnosis` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_disch_disp` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_type` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_assign_provider1` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`encounter_assign_provider2` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Obsolete - should be dropped in future',
`encounter_admit_mode` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`load_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`enc_admit` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Datetime of inpatient admission.',
`import_loc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Source of record: typically file name and line number',
`import_line` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`attend_provider_uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`disch_time_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`last_adt_recorded_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The EVN.2 recorded timestamp of the last ADT update applied. Used to ensure updates are applied in order.',
`loaded_disch_disp` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The discharge disposition originally loaded from ED Log for this chart',
`admitted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`injury_real_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`lmp_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Menstrual Period',
`transfer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Coded in patient header when patient was transferred between facilities',
`transfer_dest` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If chart is a transfer to another facility, the coder specifies the facility in this field',
`dos_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
`outpatient` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`discharge` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`encounter_uid`),
KEY `idx_fac_id` (`facility_id`),
KEY `idx_name` (`patient_name`),
KEY `idx_dos` (`encounter_dos`),
KEY `attend_provider_uid` (`attend_provider_uid`),
KEY `idx_fin` (`patient_fin`),
KEY `idx_ins` (`encounter_primary_type`),
KEY `idx_prov` (`encounter_assign_provider1`),
KEY `idx_mrn_temp` (`patient_mrn`),
CONSTRAINT `tbl_encounter_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attend_provider_uid`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_uid`)
```

)

> for tbl_code_weight

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl_code_weight` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`weight` float NOT NULL,
KEY `idx_composite` (`code`,`weight`)
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

)

Comment: please enter some details and do some formatting, start form here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this query takes about 11 seconds to execute which is really not good for application.

Comment: You could remove the inverted commas. And change the subqueries to regular joins. Beyond that we'd need to look at indexes, which means providing the EXPLAIN for the revised query, as well as CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables.

Comment: changing subqueries to regular joins does not work rather it increases the execution time to 110 sec. I have provided the explain table please go through it.

Comment: You currently have 2 bottle necks, the main where clauses and the main union, where the explain table shows using file sort. If changing from subqueries to joins makes it worse, you are doing something wrong. You should check you have indexes on the joined columns and the queried columns.

Comment: i have added all the requirements as suggested now would you please look at them and help me

Comment: Some columns in your joins and where clauses are not indexed. First step, try to index all of them.

Comment: i indexed all of them and now the execution time is 34 sec. Its still not working

Comment: Did you try converting to join? Please update new query and create table statement.

Comment: i have updated the query and table.

Comment: Some columns are still not indexed, e.g., `tbl_encounter_detail.encounter_uid, tbl_encounter_detail.work_item_uid, tbl_encounter_detail.qa_complete, tbl_event_cpt_pro.encounter_uid, tbl_event_cpt_pro.qa_disagree` and many in other tables. You should index all columns used in a comparison operation, such as join, where, conditioning.

Comment: I think rechecking and indexing will solve your problem. Unless there are too much data that even optimized query does not help.

Comment: except the column tbl_event_cpt_pro.qa_disagree every other columns has been indexed but now i have indexed all the needed columns in every tables, still the execution time is 27 sec

Comment: You need better indexes. Start with adding the indexes `tbl_encounter_detail(qa_complete, code_assigned, encounter_uid, work_item_uid)`,  `tbl_event_cpt_pro(encounter_uid, work_item_uid)`, `tbl_event_cpt_fac(encounter_uid, work_item_uid)` and `tbl_code_weight(code, weight)`. It would help if `tbl_event_cpt_pro(encounter_uid, work_item_uid)` is unique  (and the same for `tbl_event_cpt_fac`) . You may have to reorder your joins to start with `from tbl_encounter_detail as e straight_join tbl_event_cpt_pro AS tcp ...`.

Comment: @Solarflare have you seen the create table of every tables? all of the columns you mentioned has been indexed. In case of reordering  the joins this increases query execution time to 60s.

Comment: @anand You have indexes on single columns. They won't help (much). I meant a composite index that uses several columns in the given specific order. Just as you did with your index `work_item_uid_2` for your foreign key, which I indeed missed, and which can be used instead of my proposed 2nd and 3rd index. But the really important index is the first one. It should remove the filesort and enforce a different join order (if not, use, as proposed, the `straight_join`, or post the new explain plan)

Comment: ok i did index the first one as you said but then i don't think that foreign key can be maintained

Comment: wow @Solarflare it has not removed filesort and reodering the joins  from tbl_encounter_detail as e straight_join tbl_event_cpt_pro AS tcp .. as you suggested...will only allow join for tbl_encounter and tbl_event_cpt_pro or fac but the other table tbl_code_weight has relation only with tbl_event_cpt_pro and fac and not with tbl_encounter_detail.

Comment: i have added new explain plan ..Please view

Comment: Could you just try the `straight_join` instead of not trying it because you think you cannot join to other tables anymore? If you run into an error, tell it to us, otherwise, the straight join will simply force MySQL to choose a different execution plan, it doesn't change anything else.

Comment: straight_join  did not work as it takes 47 sec to execute

Comment: Can you add the execution plan?

Comment: i have added new explain plan please go through the new execution plan

Comment: You have to use `from tbl_encounter_detail as e straight_join tbl_event_cpt_pro AS tcp on tcp.encounter_uid = e.encounter_uid AND tcp.work_item_uid = e.work_item_uid JOIN tbl_encounter as ed ON tcp.encounter_uid = ed.encounter_uid LEFT JOIN tbl_code_weight AS tcd ON tcd.code = tcp.procedure_num`

Comment: this now takes 20 sec to execute and i have also added the execution plan

Comment: i have updated everything. can you please see what have i done wrong?

Comment: It's fine up to here. Next things: is `tbl_event_cpt_pro(work_item_uid,encounter_uid)` unique or not? Is `tbl_code_weight(code)` unique or not? (According to your execution plan, `code` is not unique, but I'm not sure if it would make sense.)

Comment: do you mean the index or the field itself unique or not?

Comment: they are not unique

Comment: I meant is the combination `(work_item_uid,encounter_uid)` unique? In the detail table, it's already a UNIQUE KEY. You could get rid of the distinct in that case. And `code` is not unique either? How many rows per code are there on average and how many different codes are there? I would consider creating a temporary table for them to have just one row per code.

Comment: there are one code per row

Comment: thanks man for helping me a lot @Solarflare now it works as expected